# using millis() for a timer

Tags: time

Basically the user presses a button and cycles thru 3 different modes. Mode 1 the LED is on, mode 2 the LED is off and mode 3 the LED is kept on for a certain amount of time. I'm using the millis() to keep track of the time. the LED in the third mode just stays on and never switches to off. I have the Serial.Writes in there to help me debug. I have the delay after the button read since if I didnt put it in it would register a lot of button presses.

```
int ledPin = 5;
int buttonApin = 9;
int ledMode = 0;

boolean lastButton = HIGH;
boolean currentAButton = HIGH;

// debounce button
boolean debounceFUNC(boolean last)
{
    boolean current = digitalRead(buttonApin);
    if (last != current)
    {
        delay(5);
        current = digitalRead(buttonApin);
    }
    return current;
}

void setMode(int ledMode)
{
    // turns on led
    if (ledMode == 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    // turns off led
    if (ledMode == 2)
    {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
    // timer - turns off after 5000
    if (ledMode == 3)
    {
        long interval = 5000;
        unsigned long cMillis = millis();
        static unsigned long pMillis;

        if (cMillis - pMillis > interval)
        {   
        pMillis = cMillis;
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        Serial.println("On");
        Serial.println(interval - cMillis);
        }
        else
        {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        Serial.println("Off");
        }

        }
    }

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop()
{
    // sets led mode
    currentAButton = debounceFUNC(lastButton);
    delay(500);
    if (currentAButton == LOW)
    {
        ledMode++;
        Serial.println(ledMode);
    }
    else if (ledMode > 3)
    {
        ledMode = 0;
    }
    // ledMode function call
    setMode(ledMode);
}
```

screenshot of the serial monitor.

[image]

Comment: I can't spot the question here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the logic, basically your statement:

```cpp
    if (cMillis - pMillis > interval)
    {   
       pMillis = cMillis;
       digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        Serial.println("On");
        Serial.println(interval - cMillis);
    }
    else
    {
       digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
       Serial.println("Off");
    }
```

will always be true, this is as the difference in time, `cMillis - pMillis` is always greater than `interval`.

This means that it never enters the else statement to turn off the LED, and thus means the `else` statement is usually the first thing that rune at `ledMode = 3`.

What you need to do as the simplest fix is to change your comparison, change **`>` to `<`**, in the is statement:

```cpp
if (cMillis - pMillis > interval)
```

to

```cpp
if (cMillis - pMillis < interval)
```

this will ensure the LED is always on during the 5000 mS and then as soon as it is greater it will definitely go to the `else`

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your debounce logic. You want to compare the
current button state with the previous state, which is supposed to be
stored in `lastButton`. But that variable is initialized to `true` and
then *never* updated. Your program may work better if you issue
`lastButton = currentAButton` somewhere.

You can find lots of tutorials on button debouncing, and there are
several methods. The one you are using, which is based on `delay()`, is
probably the worst: it should work in this simple case, but `delay()` is
toxic as soon as your Arduino has more than one thing to do. A very
common (and my preferred) method is to just ignore the button for some
“debounce time” after you detect a state change. A debouncer function
can be based on something like:

```c++
if (now - last_state_change < DEBOUNCE_TIME)
    return last_state;
```

Then you have to detect the button presses, which is not the same as the
button being down: you don't want to interpret the down state as a
continuous stream of very fast button presses. Instead, a button press
is the button being down now whereas it was up on the previous read. A
`button_press()` function could call the `debounce()` function and then
have something like

```c++
bool press = last_state && !state;
```

This is effectively detecting falling edges of the debounced button. You
can combine the debouncer and the falling-edge detector into a single
function as follows:

```c++
bool button_press()
{
    static bool last_state;
    static uint32_t last_state_change;
    uint32_t now = millis();

    // Ignore the button during the debounce time.
    if (now - last_state_change < DEBOUNCE_TIME)
        return false;

    bool state = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
    if (state != last_state) last_state_change = now;
    bool press = last_state && !state;
    last_state = state;
    return press;
}
```

Next there is the management of the LED states. What you are trying to
implement is called a [finite state
machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), sometimes
abbreviated “FSM”. If you search the Web for that term, you will find a
few examples on how to implement it. It canonically revolves around a
`switch` statement that enumerates all the possible states and tells
what to do in each of those states. Something like

```c++
switch (state) {
    case STATE_FOO:
        if (some_condition()) {
            do_some_action();
            state = STATE_BAR;  // switch to the next state
        }
        break;
    case STATE_BAR:
        ...
}
```

Below is a FSM implementation of your LED logic. Note that you did not
completely specify what should happen when the “timed” state times out:
you could go to a forth “timed out” state, or you could just go back to
the “off” state. In the code below I've taken that last option:

```c++
void loop()
{
    static enum { OFF, TIMED, ON } state;
    static uint32_t timed_started;
    uint32_t now = millis();

    // Switch state on button press.
    if (button_press()) switch(state) {
        case OFF:    // -> TIMED
            digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
            state = TIMED;
            timed_started = now;
            break;
        case TIMED:  // -> ON
            // LED is lready on.
            state = ON;
            break;
        case ON:     // -> OFF
            digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
            state = OFF;
            break;
    }

    // Turn off after LED_ON_TIME.
    if (state == TIMED && now - timed_started >= LED_ON_TIME) {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
        state = OFF;
    }
}
```

Note that it would have been more “canonical” to have the tests
`if (button_press())` inside the `switch` rather than the other way
around. Then the test for the timeout would also be inside the same big
`switch`. It's just that it seemed easier to me to write it this way.

For the sake of testability, here are the pieces that would be missing
for having a complete working program:

```c++
const int BUTTON_PIN = 9;
const int LED_PIN = LED_BUILTIN;
const uint32_t DEBOUNCE_TIME = 50;
const uint32_t LED_ON_TIME = 5000;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

// button_press() and loop() as above.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The debounce has been an issue and I really wanted to get away from using the delay function. Thank you for the finite state machine information. I will be looking more into it.